# Interplanetary conflict, some disease destroys the ability to understand or appreciate music

Tags: story-identification, novel

There is some kind of interplanetary conflict going on between different human factions (aliens may or may not be involved). As a relatively minor plot point a group of or all humans have lost the ability to appreciate or comprehend music through a virus or other disease. I believe it changed their DNA so the (loss) trait was inherited.

Comment: Is the disease called "modern-day record companies"?

Comment: better duplicate target at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/238206/novel-about-a-replica-of-earth-where-history-happened-slightly-differently-after

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's  Alastair Reynolds "[Century Rain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Century_Rain)" (my personal favourite among Reynolds' novels). The war is between two human factions - "Threshers" (derived from "threshold", since they don't allow technology beyond a certain level of complexity) and "Slashers", who embrace nanotechnology. Earth was an early casualty in their conflict.

No aliens per se, but Alien artifacts (artifical wormholes, copies of planet Earth).

Haven't the book with me, but e.g. this review specifically mentions the "[amusica virus](https://schicksalgemeinschaft.wordpress.com/2015/10/09/century-rain-alastair-reynolds-2004/)" (strange review by the way, since music actually has a big role in the novel). Also [this one](http://hammysbooks.blogspot.com/2016/12/century-rain-alastair-reynolds.html).

Made it even into [TV tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Creator/AlastairReynolds) (there goes the rest of your day):

> Dreadful Musician: Averted in Century Rain: in an early scene the
>   protagonist is walking into a superior's office while he plays a
>   violin, with her Internal Monologue noting how grating and painful the
>   music is. It is then revealed that she, along with a large portion of
>   the rest of the human race, were infected with a designer-disease
>   called 'amusica', which prevented people from enjoying music, to ruin
>   their side's morale. After all, someone who can't appreciate music
>   can't get patriotic fervor from their anthems, now can they?